# Try catch can't catch error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have website with masonry blog. I use Masonry js plugin (http://masonry.desandro.com/).

But if page doesn't have blog ( for example about page ) I get js error in console:

```
Bad masonry element: null
```

I try to use "try catch"

```
(function($){

    "use strict";

    $(document).ready(function(){

        try {
            var container = document.querySelector('#masonry');
            var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
                itemSelector: '.post-item'
            });
        } catch(err) {

        }

    });

})(window.jQuery);
```

But I still get this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try catch statement is used to catch and handle errors, not to disable them.
Try prevent error using the following code:

```
(function($){

    "use strict";

    $(document).ready(function(){

            if($("#masonry").length) {
               var container = document.querySelector('#masonry');
               var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
                 itemSelector: '.post-item'
               });
            }

    });

})(window.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you see in the console is logged by the plugin explicitly.

If you put

```
catch(err) {
    console.log('exception is caught', err);
}
```

You will see the exception is being caught just fine.
To prevent that message from appearing, you can add a check to the container

```
var container = document.querySelector('#masonry');
if(container){
    var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
        itemSelector: '.post-item'
    });
}
```